# Layers dont show up when exporting file from illustrator to photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, layers, export

I made a graphic in Illustrator and wanted to add finishing touches in Photoshop. But when I export the file as a PSD from Illustrator, only one layer shows up in Photoshop. I use RGB color mode and check the Write Layers option. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Click the waffle in the layer window and next in the dropdown menu select

**Release to layers (Sequence)**

[image]

After that you are good to go to export it. But make sure you select **Write layers**

[image]